# How to set landscape orientation mode for certain pages in a flutter app?

Tags: flutter, widget

I understand how to force portrait mode for the whole app. However, on certain pages, I have to display items in landscape. (these are chart details). This code works fine to display the chart but not perfect.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft, DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight])
    .then((_) {
  Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(kRouteFullScreenChart,
      arguments: data);
});
```

This does only half of the job. The user still has to rotate the device to landscape once to have the correct layout. Also when the use pushes the back button the whole interface stays in landscape mode. I am looking for something similar to "supportedInterfaceOrientations" in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, so i solved this forcing at the build function to my screen staying in landscape and not in portrait.

```
  setLandscapeOrientation()  {
     SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft]);
  }

  @override void dispose() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (MediaQuery.of(context).orientation != null)
      setLandscapeOrientation();
  }
```